# last function is getting triggered not the first one

Tags: javascript

below is my code.first getGoogleNews() function not getting triggered

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        getGoogleNews("#{@lead.full_name} + #{@lead.company}", 'person_results');
        getGoogleNews("#{@lead.company}", 'company_results');
    }
  }
  function getGoogleNews(text, div_id){
    function gcseCallback() {
      console.log(document.readyState);
      if (document.readyState != 'complete')
        return google.setOnLoadCallback(gcseCallback, true);
      google.search.cse.element.render({gname:'gsearch', div: div_id, tag:'searchresults-only', attributes:{linkTarget:''}});
      var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('gsearch');
      element.execute(text);
      $("#"+div_id).find('.loader-section').hide();
    };
    window.__gcse = {
      parsetags: 'explicit',
      callback: gcseCallback
    };
    (function() {
        var cx = '001443335100840105093:b2rosvfeghy';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
          '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
  }
```

Comment: why last function is just defined?

Comment: Can you remove the redundant details, that are not necessary and also provide error or example of how it is not executed.

Comment: "not getting triggered"...that seems unlikely. Have you stepped through it with a debugger to prove that? I would guess perhaps it's more likely that the result of the second call to the function is overwriting the result of the first one, or something like that. Or maybe a console error happens. Or maybe you're trying to write the result to an element which doesn't exist. There are many possibilities. Sadly since your stacksnippet has an error (and is incomplete - no related HTML), we can't run your code to see what is happening. It would really help us to have an example we can actually use.

Comment: `console.log()` is your friend! Add a call in right before your `googleNews()` function to ENSURE it's not being called.

Comment: `if (document.readyState != 'complete') return google.setOnLoadCallback(gcseCallback, true);` - I have my doubts that this will actually preserve the “parameters” `text` and `div_id` that were initially passed to the “outer” function `getGoogleNews`. Most likely this makes `gcseCallback` get executed in a different context, where those variables are not available.